# How to determine the sum of 2 numbers written in list representation prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to print the sum of 2 numbers written in list representation.For example for

```
suma ([5,7,3],[3,1,4],L)
```

the result should be:

```
L=[8,8,7].
```

This is the program I have written so far:

```
 add_final(E,[],[E]).
 add_final(E,[H|T],[H|T1]):-
 add_final(E,T,T1).
 invers([],[]).
 invers([H|T],L):-
 invers(T,L1),add_final(H,L1,L).

 sum([],[],T,[T]):-
               T=\=0,!.
 sum([],[],_,[]):-!.

 sum([],[L],T,[L]):-T=0,!.
 sum([L],[],T,[L]):-T=0,!.

 sum([H1|T1],[H2|T2],T,[Hs|Ts]):-
      S=H1+H2+T,
      Tn=S div 10,
      Hs=S mod 10,
      sum(T1,T2,Tn,Ts).

 suma(L1,L2,Ls):-
    invers(L1,L1i),
    invers(L2,L2i),
    sum(L1i,L2i,0,Ls).
```

The output of my program is:

```
 L = [ (3+4+0)mod 10, (7+1+ (3+4+0)div 10)mod 10, (5+3+ (7+1+ (... + ... + 0)div 10)div 10)mod 10].
```

What is going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `is` instead of `=`, so Prolog will evaluate the formula. Otherwise, it will compare terms without evaluating the math (see this [Wikibook entry](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Math,_Functions_and_Equality#Equality) for more information). If you use `=`, Prolog will unify the formula with the variable, without evaluating.

See:

```
?- A = 2+5.
A = 2+5.

?- A is 2+5.
A = 7.
```

So -- your `sum` predicate does math, so you need  to use `is`:

```
 sum([H1|T1],[H2|T2],T,[Hs|Ts]):-
      S is H1+H2+T,
      Tn is S div 10,
      Hs is S mod 10,
      sum(T1,T2,Tn,Ts).
```

Also, the resulting list will be in reverse order:

```
?- suma( [5,7,3],[3,1,4],L ).
L = [7, 8, 8]
```

You may want to revert it back in `suma`.